# Pyspark: fill missing dates with latest row value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I found various similar questions but nothing that answers my specific problem.

I need to fill missing dates rows in a pyspark dataframe with the latest row values based on a date column.

My current solution is to compute the list of missing dates till the date of today, join with original df and fill all the columns one by one with the latest valid value:

```
# get the maximum date from the df
max_date = df.select(F.max('date')).first()['max(date)')

today = datetime.date.today()
delta = today - max_date
dates_list = [(today - datetime.timedelta(days=x),) for x in range(delta.days)]

# if there are missing rows
if dates_list:
    # create df with one column 'date'
    dates_df = spark.createDataFrame(dates_list, schema=date_schema)

    # join with original df
    df = df.join(F.broadcast(dates_df), ['date'], 'outer')

    w = Window.orderBy('date').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
    
    # fill all columns with latest non null col value
    for c in df.columns:
        if c != 'date':
            df = df.withColumn(c, F.last(c, ignorenulls=True).over(w))
```

The problem with this code is that the original df contains an high number of columns and for each of them spark computes a window to get the last non-null value and this approach is quite inefficient resulting in a huge logical plan.

I would like to implement it in a way to simply get the row content with the maximum date (since  it doesn't contain null values) and change the date with the list of computed dates till today.

Any suggestion on how to implement this approach?

Example input:

```
date       | col_one | col_two | col_three | .. | col_n
-------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-15 | 0.1     | 6.5     | 9.8       | .. | 0.7
2020-08-14 | 0.2     | 5.5     | 1.8       | .. | 3.7
2020-08-13 | 0.4     | 7.5     | 1.3       | .. | 0.5
2020-08-12 | 3.1     | 8.5     | 9.8       | .. | 1.7
2020-08-11 | 0.15    | 6.9     | 9.7       | .. | 0.2
```

Example output:

```
date       | col_one | col_two | col_three | .. | col_n
-------------------------------------------------------
2020-08-18 | 0.1     | 6.5     | 9.8       | .. | 0.7
2020-08-17 | 0.1     | 6.5     | 9.8       | .. | 0.7
2020-08-16 | 0.1     | 6.5     | 9.8       | .. | 0.7
2020-08-15 | 0.1     | 6.5     | 9.8       | .. | 0.7
2020-08-14 | 0.2     | 5.5     | 1.8       | .. | 3.7
2020-08-13 | 0.4     | 7.5     | 1.3       | .. | 0.5
2020-08-12 | 3.1     | 8.5     | 9.8       | .. | 1.7
2020-08-11 | 0.15    | 6.9     | 9.7       | .. | 0.2
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample i/p and o/p?

Comment: the original df is simply a dataframe with date column and like 100 float columns, the example output simply contains all the dates till today with latest row value.

Comment: Please, add sample input and output to your question, it helps a lot and your comment did not help either.

Comment: I put two examples, hope is more clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to filter original dataframe with the maximum date, fill date column with the first missing date and union the same row content with a missing date for each remaining missing date. Then in the end join back with original df:

```
# compute the list of all dates from maximum date available till today
max_date = df.select(F.max('date')).first()['max(date)']
today = datetime.date.today()
dates_list = [today - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range((today - max_date).days)]

# take the row with latest date values
max_date_values = df.filter(F.col('date') == max_date)
missing_dates_values = None

# duplicate latest values for the dates we are missing till today
for missing_date in dates_list:
    if missing_dates_values is None:
        missing_dates_values = max_date_values.withColumn('date', F.lit(missing_date))
    else:
       missing_dates_values = missing_dates_values.unionByName(max_date_values.withColumn('date',
                                                                                        F.lit(missing_date)))

# union with the original df
if dates_list:
    df = df.unionByName(missing_dates_values)
```

In my use case the spark query plan is much more simple with respect to before leading to much better performance.